# Randomizing wp_tag_cloud() in child theme

Tags: functions, customization, categories, tags, child-theme

I'm trying to write a wordpress function code in my child theme that randomizes the words in the word cloud where previously it was alphabetized.

The code Im using is below, which doesn't work.

```
//
add_filter('wp_tag_cloud_args', 'my_wp_tag_cloud_args_filter');
function my_wp_nav_menu_args_filter($args) {
    $args['order'] = 'RAND';
    // do something
    return $args;
}
//
```

I'm able to update the wp_tag_cloud()'s default ('Order' = 'RAND') args in wp-includes/category-template.php but I know that any changes will get replaced. The change work when in that file.

How can I move those set of changes to my wordpress child theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [`tag_cloud_sort`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/tag_cloud_sort/) hook:

```php
add_filter( 'tag_cloud_sort', 'shuffle_tags', 10, 2 );
function shuffle_tags( $tags, $args ) {
    shuffle( $tags );
    return $tags;
}
```